# MySQL ON DELETE CASCADE set but doesn't delete rows from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, delete-row, cascade

In my database there are 3 tables of importance: Jobs, Login and Staff. Jobs acts as a linking table, containing both the LoginID & StaffID. I have setup cascading via PHPMyAdmin, like so:
[image]

However, when I delete a row from the Jobs table, it ONLY deletes from the jobs table and not from corresponding rows from the jobs and login table. What is the reason for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The cascading goes the other way. When you say in jobs table that it refers to login and staff and want to cascade deletes it means that when you delete an item in *login* or *staff* the deletion will cascade *into* jobs table and all rows referring to that row in *login* or *staff* will also be deleted.

So in your case jobs is the child table and login/staff are parents. You can't cascade from jobs to login and staff because that would go from child to parent.

Comment: I see, so I would actually need to delete from staff or login and then set a cascade on the other table to delete the rows?

Comment: @GoGoAllen If login and Staff rows always relate to only one row in Jobs you can set the references from them to Jobs instead of Jobs to them. Then the cascade works. But only if they always relate to a single job row.

Comment: Do I set the Foreign Key Constraint to be on JobID or StaffID (assuming from the table Staff). When I do to jobs.StaffID, I get an error? Do I need to delete the constraints set previously on the jobs table?